# How to create a <bean> tag with the Environment in Spring 5

Tags: xml, spring, annotations, autowired, applicationcontext

In Spring you can do the following using annotations:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:props.properties")
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        MyBean myBean = new MyBean;
        myBean.setEnv(env);
    }
}
```

Is the injection of Environment possible from XML?
I want something similar to:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:props.properties"/>
<bean id="env" class="org.springframework.core.env.Environment"/>
<bean id="myBean" class="MyBean" p:env-ref="env"/>
```

But I don't know if I could get properties from then env bean reference in the myBean bean declared in the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out that I can implement EnvironmentAware in MyBean to get the Environment when using XML configuration.